# How can I override Rails 3 unobtrusive javascript functions without modifying the supplied rails.js?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, overriding, unobtrusive-javascript

My Javascript isn't quite up to scratch and I'm struggling to override a function in the supplied `rails.js`.

I want to modify the way that `a[data-confirm]` are handled, using a jQuery UI modal dialogue rather than the vanilla javascript `confirm()`.

The relevant function in `rails.js` is `allowAction(element)`. If I define this in another file, I can call it from the firebug console successfully, but the `rails.js` version is still called from anchors with a `data-confirm` attribute.

I think it's because the whole `rails.js` file is wrapped in:

```
(function($) {
...
})( jQuery );
```

Is there a sensible way to override this function, *without* modifying the supplied `rails.js`?

**Edit:**

The call in `rails.js` to `allowAction` is wrapped in a `.live` call:

```
  $('a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote]').live('click.rails', function(e) {
  var link = $(this);
  if (!allowAction(link)) return false;

  if (link.attr('data-remote')) {
    handleRemote(link);
    return false;
  } else if (link.attr('data-method')) {
    handleMethod(link);
    return false;
  }   
});
```

I also tried including my javascript before and after the `rails.js`, to no avail.

**Edit:**

So, if I call `.die('click.rails')` I can then redefine the entire `click.rails` event, but the original `handleRemote()` and `handleMethod()` functions are not called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FYI, I just added an external API to the Rails jquery-ujs for exactly this sort of thing. You can now make rails.js use a custom confirm method by plugging into (and re-writing 1 line of) the `$.rails.allowAction` function.

See my article, [Rails jQuery UJS: Now Interactive](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-jquery-ujs-now-interactive/), for a full explanation with examples.

EDIT: And now, as of [this commit](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/8063d1d47ea6a08e545e9a6ba3e84af584200e41) the `confirm` dialog function can be overridden in the same way. E.g.

```
$.rails.confirm = function(message) { return myConfirmDialog(message); };
```

Comment: Even better, I just now moved the `confirm` dialog to the `$.rails` object, so it's even easier to use some other confirm dialog. See updated answer.

Comment: I was wondering how you'd go about accessing the element that triggered the confirmation so that you could customise the dialog based on that?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
//Backup our original function just in case
var backupFunc = allowAction;

//Your replacement function
var myFunc = function(element){
    //Have it your way, badabababa :)
};

//Override default 'allowAction' function

allowAction = myFunc;

/*
    Restore it the way it was before: allowAction = backupFunc;
*/
```

**EDIT:**
The scope on the functions are in a closed scope. So you will be unable to act on them as you wish.

Comment: No luck, that behaves the same as what I tried. Updated question with more info

Comment: If you are redefining the click.rails event, then can't you make it just like the original so that handleRemote() and handleMethod() *are* called?

Comment: That's what I did - copy and pasted the whole `.live` anonymous function, and replaced the `allowAction` call with `myAllowAction`. The `handleRemote` and `handleMethod` functions were undefined when I tried to call them in the copied code.

Comment: I'm not sure how Ruby works (I've never used it). So I'm not sure I can be of much more help here but I don't think you can do this. Plus the scope is closed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "the scope is closed"? It should be rails independent - it's just JS really but I tagged it as rails in case anyone using this library has tackled this before. Thanks :)

Comment: You're right, the scope is closed, so it's not possible to override these function. Please update your answer to include the scope info for clarity, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the `rails.js` code (I'm using Rails 3.0.3 and jquery-rails 0.2.7), and the point where it calls the `confirm()` method is different than yours. Mine look a lot easier to replace:

```
function allowAction(element) {
    var message = element.data('confirm');
    return !message || (fire(element, 'confirm') && confirm(message));
}
```

Maybe you can upgrade your `jquery-rails` gem (and re-run `rails generate jquery:install`)?

Comment: To confirm, your `allowAction` function is the sames as in my `rails.js`. The code I copied and pasted is the event handler that calls the `allowAction` function when a link is clicked.